# Executing EELS Analysis Script Commands

Tags: dm-script

I'm trying to use the EELSSubtractPowerLawBackground or EELSComputePowerLawBackground functions in DM-script, but I continue getting the error "Function not found." Could this be due to missing licenses or using an outdated version of GMS (I'm on 3.53 currently)?

For context, while testing this function, I have 1 spectrum open on my workspace and I have two lines of code in my script:

```
Image img := GetFrontImage()
EELSSubtractPowerLawBackground( img, 100, 200 )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use the EELS family of functions, one must have a license for the EELS Analysis package. Any installation at a facility with an EELS spectrometer or energy filter (GIF) would normally have this plug-in included, but it is not included with any installation using a GATAN-FREE license.